# Look for only specific key in child collection in $lookup

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Lets say I have collections as:

linkedDetails:

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("1234avshjd"),
 book_id:ObjectId("16262ahahha"),
 author_id:ObjectId("127hjajaj")
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("223ahha78"),
 book_id:ObjectId("1681awtsy"),
 author_id:ObjectId("127hjajaj")
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("97ahj238"),
 book_id:ObjectId("126ashs17"),
 author_id:ObjectId("127hjajaj")
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("138hajq12"),
 book_id:ObjectId("12742ahjsn"),
 author_id:ObjectId("4728haja72")
}
```

and another collection as:

bookDetails:

```
{
 _id:ObjectId("16262ahahha"),
 book_name:"harry potter",
 book_price: 10
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("1681awtsy"),
 book_name:"lotr",
 book_price: 10
}

{
 _id:ObjectId("126ashs17"),
 book_name:"song of sea",
 book_price: 10
}
```

I want to fetch record for

```
author_id:ObjectId("127hjajaj")
```

from **linkedDetails** collection match for author_id.

Lookup record from **bookDetails** collection based on book_id present
in **linkedDetails** collection for fetched author_id

From **bookDetails** collection get only book name.

For this I tried as:

```
linkedDetails.aggregate({

    {"$match": { 
  
       author_id:ObjectId("4728haja72") 
    }},
    {"$lookup":{
        "from":'bookDetails',
        "localField": '_id',
        "foreignField": 'book_id',

    }} 
})
```

If anyone needs any further information please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Your `localField` will be `book_id` and `foreignField` will be `id`.

```
linkedDetails.aggregate(
  {
    "$match": {

      author_id: ObjectId("4728haja72")
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": 'bookDetails',
      "localField": 'book_id',
      "foreignField": '_id',
      "as": "books"
    }
  }
)
```

[Here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DE3aojmK_ZN) is the mongo playground for it.

Comment: Thank you for your time, but what I need is to get only book name from bookDetails collection.